# Stored Procedure passing control back too quickily - VB6

Tags: sql, vb6

I have a stored procedure that is updating a very large table (with over 100 million records).  The stored procedure is updating records in this table.

The steps are as follows:

1. Store record IDs to be updated in a recordset (not all records will be updated - only about 20000)
2. Loop through the recordset and call the stored procedure for each record ID in the recordset
3. Each time the stored procedure has finished (for each record in the recordset mentioned in part 1), update a flag in a table to say that the update completed.

I am finding some strange behaviour.  It appears that the stored procedure is passing control back to VB6 before it has completed its updates and is continuing processing the next record.  The stored procedure is then timing out later on (on another record ID).  Therefore there are flags that say updated (step 3), even though the stored procedure has not run (because it timed out).  Is this normal behaviour i.e. for the stored procedure to pass control back to VB6 before it has finished the work?

I have Googled this and I have discovered that it could be because of the way the stored procedure is optimised by SQL Server.  I would expect control only to be passed back to VB6 after the updates have completed.  Is this not the case?

Please note that I realise there may be better ways of approaching this.  My question specifically relates to SQL Server passing control back to VB6 before it has finished the work (update).

Comment: Can you post some code and definitely some SQL.  There are people on here that could greatly optimise your queries.

Comment: @Paul, thanks.  I realise this, but the question is more specific.  Can SQL Server (stored procedure) pass control back to VB6 before it has finished a series of updates?

Comment: Please show us your code for how you are opening your record set as well as your code for how you are calling the stored procedure.

Comment: I will have to do this tomorrow.  Is it possible for the stored procedure to pass control back to the program before it has finished processing the SQL statements contained?

Comment: it sound maybe you declared adobd connection o the execution of the method how async so the instructions it being executed async, post some code

Comment: It is possible if it is operating asynchronously.

Comment: This really wouldn't be a VB6 issue, but a SQL Server behavior any client might suffer with.

Comment: My first guess would be that the client is timing out.  Sometimes I use a timer to see if it always fails after 60 seconds (for example).  What is your SQL command timeout set to?

Comment: @Alex, sorry for the delay responding.  The SQL command timeouts are set to the default i.e. 30 seconds.  It appears that the stored procedure is passing control back to VB6 before it has finished (the stored procedure contains delete statements within cursors).  This is only happening after the stored procedure times out for the first time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article proved to be the solution to this problem: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/20/Use-Caution-with-Explicit-Transactions-in-Stored-Procedures.aspx.  It appears that the following behaviour was happening:

1) Record 1.  Run stored procedure and create transaction.  Timeout on SQL Command object occurrs.
2) Record 2.  Run stored procedure successfully.  Return constrol to VB6 to update flag in database.
3) Record 3.  Run stored procedure successfully.  Return constrol to VB6 to update flag in database.
4) Record 4.  Run stored procedure successfully.  Return constrol to VB6 to update flag in database.
5) Program ends.  Stored procedure rolls back transaction (transaction now encompasses records 1-4).  Therefore records 1-4 are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you...

- run the code in sql management studio and see what happens and report back? if so i will update this answer as that will help us understand if its the code / connection or sql.

other things to investigate, given we dont not what cases you have tested for...

- use the same code path in ur vb application and change only the sql in the stored procedure to something very simple but has the same signature as far as what its doing (ie/ basica reading if there is reading, basic deleting if there is deleting, and same for updating and adding) to see what happens.

Also, some other thoughts...

- if you are using MSSQL, it's as simple as someone leaving a query window open and it ties up the database. This is easily tested. I've had the same trouble before. I've run stored procedures before that had no timeout, that normally would run immediately but would sit overnight and not run. Only to realize another person left their query window open. Close their window and poof it finally runs. Check this out, it could be a table lock. Whether it be the application doing it, or it is being done by another user making queries to the DB. Check to make sure your application is closing connections to the DB each time their being used.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand why it is timeing out (one of the table columns needs indexing).  However, the question specifically asks why SQL server seems to pass control back too early.  For example, there are 100 record ID's that all need to call the stored procedure.  Record 51 times out (records 1-50 were successful).  It appears that SQL Server is reporting success back for records 51-100 even though they are failing.